# Zend Framework , Trouble with paths

Tags: css, zend-framework, base-url

I'm doing my first zend application, following the official user's guide, I set up a standard zend application (with zend studio 9 and ZF 1.11) and I want to add images and CSS stylesheets to my .phtml pages. When I put the css files in "myApplicationName/public/css" everything works fine, but when I try to put them in another directory such as "myApplicationName/application/layouts/css",  they don't get considered, 
what kind of paths should i use to link them to phtml pages?

I've tried relative paths, things like :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="../../css/layout_look_like.css" />
```

and also :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/application/layouts/css/layout_look_like.css" />
```

but it doesn't seem to work,

I've also tried paths with $this->baseUrl(), but `<?php echo $this->baseUrl();?>` returns nothing.

thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CSS files should be inside the `public` directory. There should be no need to place them in your `application` directory. If you *really* need to do it, you could make a symbolic link to the `public` directory.

To include a CSS file (stored in the `public` directory) to your view/layout, use:

```
<?php echo $this->headLink()->appendStylesheet($this->baseUrl('/styles/basic.css')); ?>
```

Comment: You should use `$this->baseUrl('/styles/basic.css')` instead of just the path. Otherwise you may run into problems when your application runs from a subdirectory and your baseUrl therefore isn't /

Comment: ok thanks for your response, i was planning to put the layout and its css into the same directory.

Comment: But what is the directory structure for .css and .js files? Which one is correct if I use modules with ZF: `Module/views/scripts/js` and `Module/views/scripts/css`? Or `Module/views/js` and `Module/views/css`? Or `Module/views/scripts/controllerName/css` and `Module/views/scripts/controllerName/js`?  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

CSS, Images, and JS and any other publicly accessible static assets must live under the `public` folder as this is your web server DOCUMENT_ROOT (ie. http://yourdomain/). Beyond that you can use whatever structure you like.

Comment: But what if I use Module Structure where do I have to store my css and js files? Each module represents one separate page. And each page has its own styles and js scripts. Do I have to anyway put those files into /public directory? Or should I do this `Module/views/scripts/css` or this `Module/views/scripts/controllerName/js`? And what exactly css and js have to be stored in `/public`? Files that belongs to layout.phtml? But isn't it better to store layout's css and js in `/layout/script/css` and `/layoutscript/js`?

Comment: `/public` is the only thing that should be accessible via URL so you can server css/js directly out of your Module structure. If you really want to store them here, then i suppose you could use symlinks `Symfony 1.x` does something similar in its plugin infrastructure.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write like below mentioned code for your layout_look_like.css file

```
echo $this->headLink()->appendStylesheet($this->baseUrl('/css/layout_look_like.css'));
```